# How to fix hyperlink bug with css animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm building my new own website, and i want to make it gorgeous. Unfortunate, i have a problem( or a bug?) with CSS border hover animation and hyperlink.

This is a standard border animation made with pure CSS. It's about transition of border around every listed item.

I tried to change z-index of li and a href but it didn't change anything.

```css
li:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  left: 18%;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  background: transparent;
  border: 6px solid transparent;
}

li:hover:before {
  animation: animate 0.25s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes animate {
  0% {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top-color: gold;
    border-bottom-color: transparent;
    border-right-color: transparent;
    border-left-color: transparent;
  }
  50% {
    width: 80%;
    height: 0;
    border-top-color: gold;
    border-bottom-color: transparent;
    border-right-color: gold;
    border-left-color: transparent;
  }
  100% {
    width: 80%;
    height: 80%;
    border-top-color: gold;
    border-bottom-color: transparent;
    border-right-color: gold;
    border-left-color: transparent;
  }
}

li:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 30%;
  left: 18%;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  background: transparent;
  border: 3px solid transparent;
}

li:hover:after {
  animation: animate2 0.25s linear forwards;
  animation-delay: 0.25s;
}

@keyframes animate2 {
  0% {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top-color: transparent;
    border-bottom-color: transparent;
    border-right-color: transparent;
    border-left-color: gold;
  }
  50% {
    width: 0;
    height: 80%;
    border-top-color: transparent;
    border-bottom-color: gold;
    border-right-color: transparent;
    border-left-color: gold;
  }
  100% {
    width: 80%;
    height: 80%;
    border-top-color: transparent;
    border-bottom-color: gold;
    border-right-color: transparent;
    border-left-color: gold;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <h2>
        <a class="border-animation" href="#home"><img src="img/house.png" style="width:100px;height:100px" alt="">
          <p>HOME</p>
        </a>
      </h2>
    </li>

    and a few more </ul>
</div>
```

I expected it work properly, but when the animation is done hyperlink breaks out, and its not anymore a hyperlink, i mean that u cannot click on it anymore. Does anyone has some solution to solve this?

Comment: Your before and after pseudo element is positioned absolutely so it is on top of your normal content, if you set them to `z-index: -1`, they will go under the `li` and you will be able to click on it. Not sure how your page works but this won't work if you have some background colour or image because -1 zindex will put the before and after below them

Comment: if intrested in a different idea! https://stackoverflow.com/a/48695388/8620333

Comment: You might try adding the `::before` pseudo-element [to the `<a>` element](https://jsfiddle.net/mnr8jpuo/) instead of the `<li>`. See [anchor element not working when ::before pseudo element](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29032528/924299): "You've absolutely positioned the pseudo-element over the link... move the pseudo-element to the actual link instead."